# Возрат таблицы из функции

Tags: sql, sql-server

Привет. Подскажите как возвратить таблицу результатов из функции. 
Нашел один пример:

```
--CREATE TABLE TYPE 

CREATE TYPE departmentType AS TABLE
(ids int not null,nums int);

--CREATE TABLE 
CREATE TABLE #dallasTable
(ids int not null,nums int);
*/


CREATE PROCEDURE insertProc
@Dallas departmentType READONLY
AS SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO #dallasTable (ids,nums)
SELECT * FROM @Dallas
GO
DECLARE @Dallas AS departmentType;
INSERT INTO @Dallas(ids ,nums )

--select from TABLE 
SELECT * FROM up 


EXEC insertProc @Dallas;
```

Он некорректно работает. Что-то не ясно как возвращать результаты... Не совсем понятен синтаксис.

Comment: У вас тут нет функции - только хранимая процедура! Если хотите получить таблицу из функции то используйте этот шаблон `CREATE FUNCTION FunctionName(@parameter1 int, parameter2 int, ... )
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
 SELECT ...
 FROM ...
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно или вернуть результат напрямую, без временной таблицы:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertProc
    @Dallas departmentType READONLY
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT * FROM @Dallas
GO

DECLARE @Dallas AS departmentType;
INSERT INTO @Dallas(ids, nums)
VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4) 

EXEC insertProc @Dallas;
```

Или через временную таблицу, как у вас - но тогда надо выбрать из нее данные после выполнения процедуры - т.к. сама процедура ничего не вернет:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertProc
    @Dallas departmentType READONLY
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO #dallasTable
    SELECT * FROM @Dallas
GO

-- создать временную таблицу перед выполнением!
CREATE TABLE #dallasTable
(ids int not null,nums int);
GO

DECLARE @Dallas AS departmentType;
INSERT INTO @Dallas(ids, nums)
VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4) 

EXEC insertProc @Dallas;

-- выбрать результат
SELECT * FROM #dallasTable
```